# SQL Computed Column, CountIF 2 Tables

Tags: sql, count, calculated-columns

I have two tables

- tblData_VendorMasterSSPaymentTerms
- tblData_VendorMasterSSPaymentTermsCLM

tblData_VendorMasterSSPaymentTerms contains a field labled VMSSPayTerms_AribaContractID which the values exist in table tblData_VendorMasterSSPaymentTermsCLM

So in table tblData_VendorMasterSSPaymentTermsCLM I want to create a calculated column that counts how many records in tblData_VendorMasterSSPaymentTerms contains the Contract ID for that record.

This is what I have put together so far but it is still coming up with an error

```
SELECT Count(VMSSPayTerms_AribaContractID)
From tblData_VendorMasterSSPaymentTerms
Where VMSSPayTerms_AribaContractID=VMSSPayTermsCLM_ContractID
```

Can someone help me identify what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You must join the tables, group by VMSSPayTermsCLM_ContractID and count:

```
select
  c.VMSSPayTermsCLM_ContractID,
  count(t.VMSSPayTerms_AribaContractID) counter
from tblData_VendorMasterSSPaymentTermsCLM c inner join tblData_VendorMasterSSPaymentTerms t
on t.VMSSPayTerms_AribaContractID = c.VMSSPayTermsCLM_ContractID
group by c.VMSSPayTermsCLM_ContractID
```

Comment: What exactly you mean by computed column? Do you want to alter the table and add a new computed column? This would need to create a function so to reference other table.